# MySQL: Partial match search across two column range

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select from a table where the value is between two columns, with partial match. Here's the data set:

```
start_num    end_num
 180000       180099
```

I can get the row with:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE 180000
BETWEEN `start_num` 
AND IFNULL(`end_num`, `start_num`)
```

But I want to be able to grab the row from a partial match like `1800`, not just the full number. I've tried to incorporate LIKE and can't seem to figure it out. Both columns are BIGINT.

Any ideas?

Comment: A partial match with just `start_num`? or with `end_num` as well?

Comment: Really any partial match within that range of 180000 to 180099. The statement above finds the row for everything between the range (i.e 180050 works), so the partial match only needs to work until it reaches the start_num. For context, I'll be doing a lookup based on an API call where the minimum number of digits to search will be 4.